# Rails devise destroy session routing incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The application's routes is defined as follows, as registrations and session handling require tweaks:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions:  'users/sessions' } 
resources :users do
end
```

*(sign-in works as expected)*   The following link

```
<%= link_to(fa_icon('sign-out', class: 'fa-2x'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:'nav-icon') %>
```

is rendered as

```
<a class="nav-icon" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i></a>
```

which corresponds to the routes handled by the application:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
```

and so far, consistent with documentation.

However, clicking on the link returns an error in  the brower `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show` 
while the log states:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

The link appears correct with `method: :delete`, so the routing appears to be the culprit.

What is incorrect here ?

Comment: There are mostly likely two things going on here - the first is that Rails UJS is broken so that the browser is sending a GET request and not a DELETE request. Check the rails logs and the console in the browser for errors. The second is that you have to change `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `:get` if you want Devise to generate a GET route. Otherwise the request will be matched by `GET /users/:id`.

Comment: A quick fix is to use `button_to(fa_icon('sign-out', class: 'fa-2x'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:'nav-icon')` instead which does not rely on JS. You then should go through the steps of checking if you have included Rails UJS and if its actually being loaded on the page and if there are any other issues preventing it from working. Its an extremely common problem but the only real solution is debugging work. On a side note you should provide some sort of text as well so that people that rely on assistive devices can actually sign off on your site.

Comment: You are dead-on.  `button_to` was a fix and therefore there is an issue with rails UJS. Comparing this app to another, with identical set-up I see one difference: the pre-cooked 6.1.3 rails `application.js`  states: `import Rails from "@rails/ujs"  [...] Rails.start()` whereas a functioning 6.0.3 just has `require("@rails/ujs").start()`.  good heads up for the accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

@max, had it right.

Practically speaking, the default set-up of a rails 6.1.3 comes with an `application.js` file as follows:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"

[presumably all imports and requires go in between]

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

But that is leading to broken UJS.

```
button_to(fa_icon('sign-out', class: 'fa-2x'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:'nav-icon')
```

Reverting to an earlier syntaxic form

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
```

allows the link_to to function (even though usability directs us to use buttons)